# Inline assembly, getting into interrupt

Tags: c, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

Good day.
I faced a problem that I couldn't solve for several days. The error appears when I try to compile this function in C language.

```
void GetInInterrupt(UChar Interrupt)
{
    //asm volatile(".intel_syntax noprefix");
    asm volatile
    (
        "movb %0, %%al\n"
        "movb %%al, 1(point)\n"
        "point:\n"
        "int $0\n"
        : /*output*/ : "r" (Interrupt) /*input*/ : /*clobbered*/
    );
    //asm volatile(".att_syntax noprefix");
}
```

Message I get from gas is following:

```
Error: junk '(point)' after expression
```

---

As I can understand the pointer in second line is faulty, but unfortunately I can't solve it by my own.

---

Thank you for help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do [and you should add `"al"` (or eax) to your "clobbered list", or the compiler will sooner or later do something with eax that ruins your plans here. Do you want to invoke a divide by zero error?

Comment: adding "al" to the clobbered list is a good idea, thanks.
I actually want to change a $0 after an "int" command to the value stored in an "Interrupt" variable

Comment: You can't do that - code is read-only. You'll have to write a lot more code, including adding code for `mprotect` or `VirtualProtect` to allow you to set the code to read-write instead of read-only. Why don't you know which interrupt you want to call?

Comment: This code won't be executed either on linux or windows. This is a part of a interrupt handling module of an OS. Can't I somehow configure GCC to allow this internal change?

Comment: Well, obviously, if it's part of your OS, then you can do watever you like. But I still don't see what the benefit is. If it's hardware interrupts, you need no code for it. If you are dealing with software interrupts for calling the OS itself, then you (hopefully) know what the interrupt is that you are using... But I have written an answer to show you how you'd do it. Although it is quite pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++, then this one:

```
template <int N> static inline void GetInInterrupt (void)
{
    __asm__ ("int %0\n" : "N"(N));
}
```

will do. If I use that template like:

```
GetInInterrupt<123>();
GetInInterrupt<3>();
GetInInterrupt<23>();
GetInInterrupt<0>();
```

that creates the following object code:

```
   0:   cd 7b                   int    $0x7b
   2:   cc                      int3
   3:   cd 17                   int    $0x17
   5:   cd 00                   int    $0x0
```

which is pretty much optimal (even for the `int3` case, which is the breakpoint op). It'll also create a compile-time warning if the operand is out of the `0..255` range, due to the `N` constraint allowing only that.

**Edit:** plain old C-style macros work as well, of course:

```
#define GetInInterrupt(arg) __asm__("int %0\n" : : "N"((arg)) : "cc", "memory")
```

creates the same code as the C++ templated function. Due to the way `int` behaves, it's a good idea to tell the compiler (via the `"cc", "memory"` constraints) about the barrier semantics, to make sure it doesn't try to re-order instructions when embedding the inline assembly.

The limitation of both is, obviously, the fact that the interrupt number must be a compile-time constant. If you absolutely don't want that, then creating a `switch()` statement created e.g. with the help of `BOOST_PP_REPEAT()` covering all 255 cases is a better option than self-modifying code, i.e. like:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.html>

#define GET_INTO_INT(a, INT, d) case INT: GetInInterrupt<INT>(); break;

void GetInInterrupt(int interruptNumber)
{
    switch(interruptNumber) {
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(256, GET_INTO_INT, 0)
    default:
        runtime_error("interrupt Number %d out of range", interruptNumber);
    }
}
```

This *can* be done in plain C (if you change the templated function invocation for a plain `__asm__` of course) - because the boost preprocessor library does *not* depend on a C++ compiler ... and gcc 4.7.2 creates the following code for this:

```
GetInInterrupt:
.LFB0:
        cmpl    $255, %edi
        jbe     .L262
        movl    %edi, %esi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        jmp     runtime_error
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L262:
        movl    %edi, %edi
        jmp     *.L259(,%rdi,8)
        .section        .rodata
        .align 8
        .align 4
.L259:
        .quad   .L3
        .quad   .L4
[ ... ]
        .quad   .L258
        .text
.L257:
#APP
# 17 "tccc.c" 1
        int $254

# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        ret
[ ... accordingly for the other vectors ... ]
```

Beware though if you do the above ... the compiler (gcc up to and including 4.8) is *not* intelligent enough to optimize the `switch()` away, i.e. even if you say `static __inline__ ...` it'll create the full jump table version of `GetInInterrupt(3)` instead of just an inlined `int3` as would the simpler implementations.

Comment: Are you missing a second : in that template.  I think it might need to be:     template <int N> static inline void raiseInterrupt (void)
    {
        asm volatile ("int %0\n" : : "N"(N));
    }

Answer (score 2):

Below show how you could write to a location in the code. It does assume that the code is writeable in the first place, which is typically not the case in mainstream OS's - since that would hide some nasty bugs.

```
void GetInInterrupt(UChar Interrupt)
{
    //asm volatile(".intel_syntax noprefix");
    asm volatile
    (
        "movb %0, point+1\n"
        "point:\n"
        "int $0\n"
        : /*output*/ : "r" (Interrupt) /*input*/ : /*clobbered */
    );
    //asm volatile(".att_syntax noprefix");
}
```

I also simplified the code to avoid using two registers, and instead just using the register that `Interrupt` already is in. If the compiler moans about it, you may find that `"a"` instead or `"r"` solves the problem.

Comment: This code modifies instruction memory, but does not flushes cpu pipeline. Thus wrong interrupt may be called.